# Java SE and Weld?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, weld

I'm currently testing CDI 2.0 for Java SE (weld) - I read, that it won't be necessary to use a beans.xml, so I tried this out:

Hallo.class:

```
public class Hallo {

   public String sayHallo() {
      return "hallo";
   }
}
```

Then i have a Test.class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Test {

@Inject Hallo hallo;

   public String sayHallo() {
      return hallo.sayHallo() + " from Test";
   }
}
```

And finally here im trying to use CDI:

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SeContainerInitializer initializer = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
    /** disable discovery and register classes manually */
    try (SeContainer container = initializer.disableDiscovery().addPackages(Demo.class).initialize()) {
        Test test = container.select(Test.class).get();
        test.sayHallo();
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I get this Messages:

> Okt 10, 2018 2:22:04 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup 
>   INFO: WELD-000900: 3.0.5 (Final)
>   Okt 10, 2018 2:22:05 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
>   INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
>   Okt 10, 2018 2:22:05 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer fireContainerInitializedEvent
>   INFO: WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container 5adc2948-acd7-423c-84dc-c1463534c309 initialized
>   Okt 10, 2018 2:22:05 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer shutdown
>   INFO: WELD-ENV-002001: Weld SE container 5adc2948-acd7-423c-84dc-c1463534c309 shut down

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CDI container is working fine.
`Transactional services not available` states you are not running under a Transaction Manager, which you'd have (almost) by default running inside an application server.